# Sentence structure. when the sentence is a subordinate clause and has a subject of proper noun

Tags: subordonnées, inversion

Before start, sorry for my poor English because English is a unfamiliar language for me.

I heard a sentence "C'est ce qu'a précisé Emmanuel Macron" from RFI Le Journal en français facile, 16 June 2022.

According to the answer on other question in this site, non-pronoun subject in a subordinate clause can be inverted or not. So I tried to make that sentence not inverted.

1. C'est ce qu'Emmanuel Macron a précisé.
2. C'est ce qu'Emmanuel Macron a-t-il précisé.

Are the sentences correct? If so, which is more natural for native speakers? Or not, please give me a right sentence.

Comment: Either “c'est ce qu'Emmanuel Macron a précisé” or “c'est ce qu'a précisé Emmanuel Macron”. I suppose this is what was meant in the other question. Can you provide a link to it?

Comment: [link](https://savoirs.rfi.fr/fr/apprendre-enseigner/langue-fran%C3%A7aise/journal-en-francais-facile-16062022-20h00-gmt)

Comment: I tried to make a link but it seems fail. I'm not familiar with this site sorry. https://savoirs.rfi.fr/fr/apprendre-enseigner/langue-fran%C3%A7aise/journal-en-francais-facile-16062022-20h00-gmt

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence is not correct because you already mentioned the subject of the subordinate ("Emmanuel Macron") thus you don't have to repeat it ("**-t-il**")

The first sentence is correct.